# How to change the input language when an entry gets focused in Gtk Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, keyboard-layout, input-language

I want to change the input language when an entry gets focused (or dialog is shown) in Gtk Python. In my program, a dialog appears many times and the user must enter some texts. In systems which allow different keyboard layout for each window, the user must change the input language each time the dialog is appearing. I am programming on ubuntu ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first approach was be to look at Gtk+ input methods.

The `Gtk.Entry` has the property [`im_module`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html#Gtk.Entry.props.im_module), which can be used to set the [`Gtk.IMContext`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/IMContext.html#Gtk.IMContext).
There also two blogpost ([1](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2006/12/22/creating-gtk-input-methods/), [2](https://blog.simos.info/improving-input-method-support-in-gtk-based-apps/)) and an extensive [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=keyboard%20layout%20change) about Gtk+ input methods that may help you.

My second approach was to use [xkb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.html).

You could try something like

`subprocess.run('sudo setxkbmap -layout ' + entry_lang_str)`

And then I remembered that you could also use [gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gsettings.1.html).

`gsettings set /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/ sources [('xkb', entr_lang_str)]` (also via `subprocess.run()`)

Using gsettings seems to be the easiest way for me.